# Why is my pip installation not changing on VS Code when using a VENV?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

EDIT: I can install packages by opening the venv within `cmd` and it installed to the correct location. So I think it's a problem specifically with vscode.

I am using a virtual environment in VS Code. I set it up through `python -m venv .venv` to create the environment. VS Code recognizes it and activates it. If I uses `sys.executable` it gives me the correct location.

However whenever I run `pip install <module>` or `py -m pip install <module>` it always installs to the base location of python rather than the venv, even though I am working within the venv.

When i run `pip show pip` I get the below answer:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31uiH.png)

I am thinking that when I activate the venv through vscode it isn't installing changing the path for pip for some reason.

Can anyone help me with finding a solution?

I have tried installing and reinstalling the venv, python, and vscode. I have redone my path variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `python -m pip command` instead of using the `pip` command. Which can ensure that you're using the pip module associated with the correct Python interpreter.

For example, you can install a package in your virtual environment with `python -m pip install <package>`.